# Heatmap Scale on R Statistics

Tags: r, heatmap

I'm working on a small and basic matrix I've converted into a heat map, except my color scales are only in relationshp to rows and not the entire matrix as a whole. Changing the scale to "non" leaves my heat map predominantly blank -- can someone direct me on how to adjust a scale relative to my entire matrix and not by row or column?

Comment: Can you provide some code for reproducibility? See: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: When you say "predominantly blank" that implies some cells are not blank. Are the majority of your data points of a large value and only a handful are small?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
> matrix<-matrix(data = 1:9,ncol = 3)
> heatmap(matrix, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, col = heat.colors(256), scale="none", margins=c(5,5))
```

I think that the problem could be the "non" instead of "none".